# The meaning of 'more or less' in the 'Justice League' Comicon trailer

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I watched a trailer for the new Justice League movie. At about [1:00 of the video](https://youtu.be/gglkYMGRYlE?t=1m), the dialogue goes like this:

> Diana Prince (aka the Wonderwoman) : He said he'll fight with us?
>   Bruce Wayne (aka the Batman) : More or less.
>   Diana Prince : More MORE or more LESS?
>   Bruce Wayne : Probably more less.
>   Diana Wayne : He said no.
>   Bruce Wayne : He said no.

I don't get the meaning of 'more or less', 'more more', 'more less' what does this mean?

Or is it that, although Aquaman refused Batman's offer to join the Justice League, when Wonderwoman asked him wheater Aquaman is going to join or not, Batman didn't want to sound like he failed, so he said 'more or less'?

Also, does the phrase 'more more' really exist? If so, does 'less more', 'less less' exist? (although less more seems kind of weird :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"More or less" means 'approximately', 'to a certain extent'.

In Diana Prince's follow-up question "more 'more' or more 'less'" she is asking if the Bruce Wayne is tending towards the positive side of that valuation (more, to a great extent, quite a lot) or the negative side (less, to a small extent, just a little). In other words, is he very willing to fight with us, or is he somewhat reluctant.

His answer is "Probably more less", which means he tends towards the negative side, that he is somewhat reluctant about joining them, that he has misgivings.

This just goes to show how flexible English is -- "more more" or "more less" would sound ridiculous or ungrammatical without the context in which it is said but, given the context, it works!

Out of context, these phrases would not normally exist!

Comment: So there's 1. He'll very willingly fight with the Justice League, 2. He'll somewhat fight with the Justice League 3. He's reluctant about fighting with the Justice League 4. He'll never fight with the Justice League

Comment: And the first time Batman said 'more or less' it means either 2 or 3, but when Diana asked 'more more' it means 2. and 'more less' it means 3.

Comment: But then Batman said 'more less' it means 3?

Comment: Are the interpretations I've written above correct?

Comment: You've got it!!